# The Hidden Subgroup Problem under different mappings

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing, factoring

The Hidden Subgroup Problem (HSP) is an extremely prevalent problem in quantum computation, especially for factorization in Shor’s algorithm.

The problem is stated

> Given an oracle for some function, $f: G \mapsto X$, that is promised to satisfy $g_1 H = g_2 H \iff f(g_1) = f(g_2)$

But the HSP is often spoken of in terms of the group $G$, instead of the function $f$. For example, period finding (the foundation of Shor’s algorithm) is said to be the HSP on the cyclic group ($\mathbb{Z}_N$). The graph isomorphism problem is the HSP on the symmetric group. The shortest vector lattice problem is the HSP on the dihedral group. None of these reference the mapping.

Does the complexity of the HSP change when the function is changed? Is it by a polynomial factor every time?